# Why LR/SC Atomic instructions works？

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, spinlock

I'm the beginner of the multi-threads, I found it so different from single thread programming. and this is the question:

Here are two threads: T1 and T2
If T1 want write someting to memory, it first read and set a flag to a piece of memory, then T1 need to check the 'reservation set'. If check successful, then write.

The problem is: If T1 set the flag(LR) and finish check, next step is going to write. then T2 start working, T2 set a flag, check flag and write something to the memory. Then T1 start again, T1 already checked the flag, it just writing and quit, which means T1 write to the memory and cover the result from T2. Are this possible? If so, why LR/SC can make sure the result can be stored correctly?

LR：

```
lr.{w/d}.{aqrl} rd, (rs1)
```

load rs1 to rd and make change to 'reservation set'

SC pseudocode：

```
if (is_reserved(rs1)) {
    *rs1 = rs2
    rd = 0
} else
    rd = 1
clean_reservation_set(cur_hart)
```

I tried to read handbook of RISC-V and assembly code. but it still doesn't solve the problem I described above.I wonder if my understanding of LR/SC or multithreading is wrong? If so, what kind of information do I need to consult to get a deeper understanding of them

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the RISC-V spec is a bit confusing, but in practice, the LR/SC instructions are [load-linked/store-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) synchronization primitives.

The [armv8 manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/Multi-core-processors/Multi-processing-systems/Synchronization) and [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) both describe the same primitives a bit more clearly, here's a brief overview.

The basic concept is that the `SC` instruction will only succeed if nothing modified the memory region touched by the previous `LL` instruction.

In practice, this is implemented by specially marking the **memory region** fetched by `LL` as *belonging to the current core X*, when running `LL`.
Multiple `LL`s made to addr `addr` by multiple cores will each update the "belongs to core X" tag of region `addr..(addr+wordsize)`.
The `SC` instruction will only succeed if in the "belongs to core X" tag for region `addr..(addr+wordsize)`, X=current core (which means no other `LL` instruction was run on other cores between the `LL` and `SC` instruction on our core).

For example, assume register `rs1` contains the memory address `1000` and the word size is 4 bytes.

1. The load-linked instruction (RISC-V `LR.W`/ARM `LDXR`) loads a word from the memory address in `rs1` into register `rd`, and marks the memory region `1000-1004` as *belonging to the current core*.
2. The store-conditional instruction (RISC-V `SC.W`/ARM `STXR`) checks if the memory region `1000-1004` *belongs to the current core*, and:

   2.1) If yes, writes the contents of register `rs2` to the memory address `rs1`, writes `0` to `rd` and marks the memory region `1000-1004` as **not** belonging to the current core.

   2.2) If not, just writes `1` (or another non-zero value) to `rd`.

Pseudocode:

```
// Assume a memory size of 16 bytes (4 words)

int32_t mem[] = {0, 0, 0, 0}
int32_t mark[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1}

function ll(addr) {
    mark[addr] = core
    return mem[addr]
}

function sc(addr, value) {
    if (mark[addr] == core) {
        mem[addr] = value
        mark[addr] = -1
        return 0
    }
    return 1
}
```

The following phrase from the RISC-V spec:

> Regardless of success or failure, executing an `SC.W` instruction invalidates any reservation held by this hart

Indicates that either way, at the end of both `2.1` or `2.2`, memory region `1000-1004` is **not** marked as belonging to the current core: in the first case because we explicitly marked it as not belonging to the current core, in the second case because it was already marked as belonging to another core by another core before the instruction started execution.

*Side note:*

CISC instruction sets like x86 usually implement [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (compare-and-swap) instead of [LL/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional).

CAS is different from LL/SC, mainly because it doesn't rely on the side effect of "marking a memory region as belonging to a core" to archieve synchronization: instead, it relies on the actual values residing in the memory, which can lead to problems like [ABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap#ABA_problem).

RISC-V chose to use LL/SC precisely to avoid ABA, and to avoid introducing a new integer instruction format to support three source operands (address, compare value, swap value).

LR/SC and CAS are equivalent, and each one be implemented using the other, for example here's an implementation of CAS using RISC-V LR/SC instruction, taken straight from the spec:

```
    # a0 holds address of memory location
    # a1 holds expected value
    # a2 holds desired value
    # a0 holds return value, 0 if successful, !0 otherwise
cas:
    lr.w t0, (a0)     # Load original value.
    bne t0, a1, fail  # Doesn’t match, so fail.
    sc.w t0, a2, (a0) # Try to update.
    bnez t0, cas      # Retry if store-conditional failed.
    li a0, 0          # Set return to success.
    jr ra             # Return.
fail:
    li a0, 1          # Set return to failure.
    jr ra             # Return.
```